# Removing X,Y ticks on Z axis - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'd like to remove the X- and Y-ticks that show up on the Z-axis as shown below.  MWE doesn't reproduce plot below, but using same `surfc` function:

```
N=100;
x=linspace(-2,2,N);
y=x;
f=zeros(N,N);

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        f(j,i) = x(i)*exp(-x(i)^2 - y(j)^2) + (x(i)^2 + y(j)^2)/20;
    end
end

surfc(x,y,f)
```

[image: surface]

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-part-2#Baseline) for undocumented properties that seem to do what you want on Matlab releases newer than R2014b. I don't have it so I can't test unfortunately.

Comment: Does `set( gca(), 'zticks', [] )` not work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have those by default on a simple 3D plot

```
figure, plot3(rand(500,1),rand(500,1),rand(500,1))
```

I have to specify I want a grid and they appear :

```
grid on
```

And I can remove them when I'm fed up with the grid:

```
grid off
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you should probably post a snippet of code.

Comment: indeed, for `plot3` there are no grid lines.  I've added a MWE using the `surfc` function used for the image above.  I'd like to keep the X and Y ticks but only on the X-Y plane, so `grid off` is a little aggressive.  Thanks.